# AnnotationView on a map that not geographic map

Tags: ios, maps, mkannotationview

How do I put the annotationView on a map that is not a road map but it is something like this:
[image]

Not possible to provide latitude and longitude. What do I put coordinates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is an image view and if it is image view you have to take gesture recognizer's help and get the point value(pixel) of the tapped point and set annotation their.

Comment: Thank you very much.I used a UITapGestureRecognizer for find the coordinates. Like annotation I used a UIImageView.